# How to add a property to TSpeedButton (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, inheritance, custom-component

I need to add 2 new properties to TSpeedButton.
Although the properies are correctly displayed at object inspector and its values stored at DFM file, the "create" method at runtime keep getting the properties as "nil".

What´s wrong ?

Here is the customized component code:

```
unit ulbSpeedButton;

    interface

    uses
      Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Graphics,
      Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Winapi.CommCtrl, Vcl.ImgList,
      Vcl.Themes, System.Generics.Collections, Vcl.Buttons;

    type
      tlbSpeedButton = class(TSpeedButton)
      private
        fImageList : TImageList;
        fImageIndex : Integer;
        function GetImageIndex:Integer;
        function GetImageList:TImageList;
        procedure SetImageIndex(aIndex:Integer);
        procedure SetImageList(aImageList:TImageList);
      protected

      public
        constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
      published
        property ImgIndex : Integer read fImageIndex write SetImageIndex;
        property ImgList : TImageList read GetImageList write SetImageList;
      end;

    procedure Register;

    implementation

    procedure Register;
    begin
      RegisterComponents('Leo Bruno', [tlbSpeedButton]);
    end;

    { tlbSpeedButton }

    constructor tlbSpeedButton.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
    begin
      inherited Create(AOwner);

      if ((Assigned(fImageList)) and (fImageList.Count > 0)) then
        fImageList.GetBitmap(fImageIndex,Self.Glyph);
    end;

    function tlbSpeedButton.GetImageIndex: Integer;
    begin
      Result := fImageIndex;
    end;

    function tlbSpeedButton.GetImageList: TImageList;
    begin
      Result := fImageList;
    end;

    procedure tlbSpeedButton.SetImageIndex(aIndex: Integer);
    begin
      if fImageIndex <> aIndex then
      begin
        fImageIndex := aIndex;
        Invalidate;
      end;
    end;

    procedure tlbSpeedButton.SetImageList(aImageList: TImageList);
    begin
      if fImageList <> aImageList then
      begin
        fImageList := aImageList;
        Invalidate;
      end;
    end;

    end.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to what KenWhite said, the two property setters should be updating the `Glyph` (in case the properties need to be updated in code after DFM streaming, or even just at design-time). Just make sure to make them check the `ComponentState` property for the `csLoading` flag so they don't update the `Glyph` during DFM streaming, since `Loaded()` will handle that.

And don't forget to call `FreeNotification()` on the assigned `TImageList`, since it is external to the button and could potentially be freed before the button is freed.

Try this:

```
unit ulbSpeedButton;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Winapi.CommCtrl, Vcl.ImgList,
  Vcl.Themes, System.Generics.Collections, Vcl.Buttons;

type
  tlbSpeedButton = class(TSpeedButton)
  private
    fImageList : TCustomImageList;
    fImageIndex : Integer;
    procedure SetImageIndex(aIndex: Integer);
    procedure SetImageList(aImageList: TCustomImageList);
    procedure UpdateGlyph;
  protected
    procedure Loaded; override;
    procedure Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property ImgIndex : Integer read fImageIndex write SetImageIndex default -1;
    property ImgList : TCustomImageList read fImageList write SetImageList;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Leo Bruno', [tlbSpeedButton]);
end;

{ tlbSpeedButton }

constructor tlbSpeedButton.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  fImageIndex := -1;
end;

procedure tlbSpeedButton.Loaded;
begin
  inherited;
  UpdateGlyph;
end;

procedure tlbSpeedButton.Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation);
begin
  inherited;
  if (Operation = opRemove) and (AComponent = fImageList) then
  begin
    fImageList := nil;
    UpdateGlyph;
  end;
end;

procedure tlbSpeedButton.UpdateGlyph;
begin
  if csLoading in ComponentState then Exit;
  if Assigned(fImageList) and (fImageIndex >= 0) and (fImageIndex < fImageList.Count) then
    fImageList.GetBitmap(fImageIndex, Self.Glyph)
  else
    Self.Glyph := nil;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure tlbSpeedButton.SetImageIndex(aIndex: Integer);
begin
  if fImageIndex <> aIndex then
  begin
    fImageIndex := aIndex;
    UpdateGlyph;
  end;
end;

procedure tlbSpeedButton.SetImageList(aImageList: TImageList);
begin
  if fImageList <> aImageList then
  begin
    if Assigned(fImageList) then fImageList.RemoveFreeNotification(Self);
    fImageList := aImageList;
    if Assigned(fImageList) then fImageList.FreeNotification(Self);
    UpdateGlyph;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Very nice man.Worked like a charm. Just one thing I couldn´t fix. In designtime , If I assign an imageindex and a imagelist,  the glyph is updated. But changing a already set imageindex in designtime, does not update the glyph.  Thank you very much for your time and patience.

Comment: @LeoBruno: Once the dimensions of the `Glyph` have been established, `GetBitmap()` will simply draw new images on top of the existing bitmap. I was expecting `GetBitmap()` to trigger the glyph's `OnChange` event so `TSpeedButton` would auto-`Invalidate()` itself. But apparently that is not the case, unless `GetBitmap()` has to resize the bitmap (which it does the first time). So, just make `UpdateGlyph()` call `Invalidate()` directly to force it.

Answer (score 4):

You can't access the imagelist from the component's `Create` event; it occurs before the other content has been streamed in from the .DFM file. The button has to be created before it's properties can be set, and the `Create` event happens at that time.

You need to move your code that accesses the imagelist to an overridden `Loaded` method instead, which happens *after* the entire content has been streamed in.

```
type
  tlbSpeedButton = class(TSpeedButton)
  private
    fImageList : TImageList;
    fImageIndex : Integer;
    function GetImageIndex:Integer;
    function GetImageList:TImageList;
    procedure SetImageIndex(aIndex:Integer);
    procedure SetImageList(aImageList:TImageList);
  protected
    procedure Loaded; virtual; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property ImgIndex : Integer read fImageIndex write SetImageIndex;
    property ImgList : TImageList read GetImageList write SetImageList;
  end;

implementation

  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent);
  begin
    inherited;
  end;

  procedure TlbSpeedButton.Loaded;
  begin
    inherited;
    if Asssigned(fImageList) and (fImageList.Count > 0) and
       (fImageIndex > -1)  then
      fImageList.GetBitmap(fImageIndex, Self.Glyph);
  end;  

  // The rest of your code
end;
```

Comment: The two property setters should update the `Glyph` as well, in case the properties are updated in code after DFM streaming, or even at design-time. Just make sure to make them check the `ComponentState` property for the `csLoading` flag so they don't update the `Glyph` during DFM streaming, since `Loaded()` will handle that.

Comment: @Remy: Good point. I'll update my answer when I have access to a compiler to test it before posting (to make sure I sequence things right).

Comment: And don't forget `FreeNotification()` as well, since the `TImageList` is external to the button.